# Is there any reason to use selector '*.class' over '.class'?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I found it in code and don't know what's the point of using `*.class` selector over `.class` selector.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no point to it, whether in the jQuery ([Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com)) selector context or CSS selector context. Both `*.class` and `.class` are equivalent in terms of elements matched, and specificity.

The `*` character is only significant when used by itself to refer to any element; it's implied the moment you use any other simple selector without a type selector. *Even then*, you will seldom, if ever, find yourself needing to hook events to or manipulate properties of every element on the DOM.

If you are going to use classes, pseudo-classes, IDs and so on, then there's no point having the universal selector there as the selected elements will be filtered accordingly anyway.

Furthermore, here's one shortcoming of using `*` with other selectors, quoted from the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/all-selector):

> Caution: The all, or universal, selector is extremely slow, except when used by itself.

And here's what the [Selectors spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#universal-selector) says:

> If a universal selector represented by * (i.e. without a namespace prefix) is not the only component of a [sequence of simple selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#sequence) selectors or is immediately followed by a [pseudo-element](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-elements), then the * may be omitted and the universal selector's presence implied.
>
> > Examples:
> >
> > - `*[hreflang|=en]` and `[hreflang|=en]` are equivalent,
> > - `*.warning` and `.warning` are equivalent,
> > - `*#myid` and `#myid` are equivalent.

Comment: Re performance, I thought it'd be a major difference, but I think jQuery optimizes it away in this case. jsperf.com/starsss is a basic example. I guess since the call is just a basic wrapper for document.getElementsByClass?

Comment: @yc: Sometimes jQuery may be able to hand it to `getElementsByClass`, `getElementById` or `querySelectorAll`. Even then, `*` is still microscopically yet significantly slow whether it's handled by jQuery or the browser's selector engine.

Comment: Yeah, totally. There's no reason at all to add the `*` here. No-brainer. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

They are roughly equivalent - the asterisk only further specifies which objects of said class to apply the selection to.

```
 .class // Selects all of the specific class
*.class // Selects all of the specific class - where * can be a div, li, etc.
```

Comment: What browser doesn't support `*`? Also he's talking about jQuery.

Comment: @Rionmonster: Maybe not only in older browsers, but every browsers sees `*.class` as more specific than `.class` I think. Just like `div.class`

Comment: @Marnix: `*.class` has equal specificity to `.class`.

Comment: @Rion What older browsers specifically?

Comment: Ah - I misread as well. Thought he was talking about CSS - I'll have to change that around.

Comment: Also - I believe I had used the * in CSS in the past for applying a style to most modern browsers, however if there was something that was causing issue (for instance padding/margin in IE7 Compatibility Mode) then I could use *class to apply just that older style.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no reason to specify `*.class` over `.class`

`*` is a wildcard character, and means "apply this to anything" but that's just the native selector behavior.

However, it could have been added by someone who was trying to be explicitly documentary in the face of:

> Don't select a *particular* element type, but match all element types

But this only holds true if your internal normal code-organization is of the type:

```
$('div.class')
$('a.class')
$('a:first')
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

There would be no advantage gained - I think there is a performance issue if you use wildcard with further selectors:

> Caution: The all, or universal,
>   selector is extremely slow, except
>   when used by itself.

Other than that - no difference

Comment: I thought so, but I think jQuery optimizes it away in this case. http://jsperf.com/starsss, since the call is just a basic wrapper for `document.getElementsByClass`.