# Jquery - find the next input:text element after a known element

Tags: jquery, input, jquery-selectors, element

I have an id for a `<tr id="tagTR">` 
Given the above, is it possible to find the next `input:text` element regardless of any other mark up in between . Is there a jQuery selector that I can use for this scenario?

For example :

```
<tr id="tagTR"> 
</tr>
<tr id="tagRed"> 

  <td> </td>
</tr>
<div>
 <tr>
   <td>
     <input> // This is what I want to get to. 
   </td>
 </tr>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your actual markup. You have `<tr>` elements with `<div>` parents and siblings, which is invalid HTML.

Comment: You need to use `nextAll()` to search all sibling relative to the known marker element and if what your looking for is not found, grab the list of `.parents()` of the known element and loop through each sibling of each parent to find the element in question, basically calling a `nextAll()` on each parent of your known element.

Comment: @Frederic - You are right, it's invalid HTML but it was just some sample code I put up on the fly, the question was more about finding out the next input element. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @JeffWilbert Thanks Jeff - that should help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I thought this question was very interesting. It seems others are reading this as, find the next input among siblings. But I read it as - find me the next input no matter what. I don't know if its in a sibling, a parent or a parent's sibling. This is what I came up with  based on feedback I received from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902270/is-element-before-or-after-another-element-in-dom/8902383#8902383).

http://jsfiddle.net/GesSj/1

```
//assume you know where you are starting from
var $startElement = $('#foo');

//get all text inputs
var $inputs = $('input[type=text]');

//search inputs for one that comes after starting element
for (var i = 0; i < $inputs.length; i++) {
    if (isAfter($inputs[i], $startElement)) {
        var nextInput = $inputs[i];
        alert($(nextInput).val());
    }
}

//is element before or after
function isAfter(elA, elB) {
    return ($('*').index($(elA).last()) > $('*').index($(elB).first()));
}
```

Comment: Thanks much mrtsherman. You are absolutely right, that was my intent and that's how I wanted the reader to interpret the question. Your solutions is interesting one - but I was wondering if there is a simple Jquery selector for it.

Comment: @user1006072 - unfortunately there is not. It is a pretty unusual question because usually there is SOME structure that you can depend on. Then you would use next, nextAll, filter or find.

Comment: I [posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29084305/274502) another solution based on yours. (pointing out because I just realized you may have not received any notifications from my mention there)

Answer (score 6):

### Check it out: [moved this into a more complete question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30089307/274502)

Based on the [awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8902127/274502) by  [@mrtsherman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/510314/mrtsherman), I wrote this more complete solution:

```
(function( $ ){
 $.fn.findNext = function(sel) {
   var $result = $(sel).first();
   if ($result.length <= 0) {
     return $result;
   }
   $result = [];
   var thisIndex = $('*').index($(this));
   var selIndex = Number.MAX_VALUE; // Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER is not yet fully supported
   $(sel).each(function(i,val){
     var valIndex = $('*').index($(val));
     if (thisIndex < valIndex && valIndex < selIndex) {
       selIndex = valIndex;
       $result = $(val);
     }
   });
   return $result;
 }; 
})( jQuery );
```

Then you can use it as this:

```
$('#tagTR').findNext('input');
```

I would [submit a PR](http://contribute.jquery.org/commits-and-pull-requests/) for this on jQuery lib if I knew my code was properly optimized and if it was okay by Mr T Sherman there, meaning **I think this should be a core method on jQuery**! :P

Comment: lol, thanks @vincent but why are people still using jQuery? since i don't code deep enough for a long while (and i'm too lazy right now to stfw), i honestly have no clue! 

Answer (score 1):

[@Cawas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/274502/cawas) - nice [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29084305/3939503), but I suggest to use it not excessive, because of `$('*')` is expensive ;-)

Regardless of that, I extended it for my needs:

```
(function( $ ){
     $.fn.findNextOverall = function(sel, returnItselfIfMatched) {

       if(returnItselfIfMatched && $(this).is(sel)) return $(this);

       var $result = $(sel).first();
       if ($result.length <= 0) {
         return $result;
       }
       $result = [];
       var thisIndex = $('*').index($(this));
       var selIndex = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
       $(sel).each(function(i,val){
         var valIndex = $('*').index($(val));
         if (thisIndex < valIndex && valIndex < selIndex) {
           selIndex = valIndex;
           $result = $(val);
         }
       });
       return $result;
     }; 
    })( jQuery );
```

So if `returnItselfIfMatched` is set `true` it returns itself, if it matches the selector itself. Useful, if you don't know, which element is calling and you are searching for exactly itself.

Comment: Yeah, I wonder if there's anyway to do it without `$('*')`... Now, you basically added just a very particular `if` there, which is a quite narrow usage case. I'd say this would go better as an extended function in your code or straight on the code itself.

Comment: I use it in big forms, where I've to know, which element has the focus, to apply more elements based on key-short-cuts. That the user often do that shortcuts, while focus already in that target itself . So it is more easy to put it in the plugin to produce less lines of code. But independet of that, why dont't make this if-statement. It decreases the DOM-traversing and you get no null-return in this case. The `$('*')` could be optimized by a recursive traversing through the next higher level the return at matching the first element. But for me in my project it's ok.Greetings André

Comment: Now I'm not so sure the universal selector have any performance hit, [**when used by itself**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5393740/274502). Do you happen to know any better?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a `div` tag in between `TR's`. It is not a valid markup.

To find the `input` element from the referred `tr` you can try this.

```
$('#tagTR').nextAll().filter(function(){
    return $(this).find('input:text').length > 1;
}).find('input');
```

Comment: This would only search the sibling relative to the tag for the input, based on the OP's question he wants to find the next input relative to the tag whether its in the siblings or a parent or its sibling, you just need to add on a loop of all parents of the tag with a `nextAll()` call.

Comment: In that case we don't know till what parent level OP wants to look. I think OP wants to look in all other rows.

Comment: There wouldn't be a level it'd be all parents until the next input is found or until you reach the beginning parent HTML, you have to use `.parents()` to loop through all the parents of the TR node and with each parent use `.nextAll()` to search all sibling of it for the input.  I just realized that even then that wouldn't work exactly because the parent node could have an input in it that's before where the tag element is.

Comment: That makes sense but it all depends on OP's knowledge of markup. We can first look in the siblings if not present then look in one level up and keep moving one level up until we find it.

Comment: Also the thing to keep in mind if using `.parents()` and `.nextAll()` to find the input is this for example http://jsfiddle.net/WNsaD/ look at the HTML markup.  You'd have to make sure the input found is ahead/in front of the marker element and not really behind it.

Comment: Nice discussion - thanks for all the input. Let me try to address as much as I can individually
@ShankarSangoli - Thanks much. I sort of get what you are trying to do, but not sure why the .length > 1 ?

Comment: @JeffWilbert - You are right in what you say but my intent was to start from an element that I have an ID for and assume that I don't have much info about the further mark up, I just need to get to the next input:text element. Thanks for the suggestions and comments though..

Answer (score -3):

You can use "next":

```
$("#tagTR").next("input")
```

Comment: `next` only looks at the immediately following sibling, and returns it if it matches the selector.