# jQuery selector for finding the first element after a given element that matches a selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I have this HTML:

```
 <textarea>blah</textarea>
 <br>
 <div class="select_this">hello!</div>
```

How can I select the DIV with class "select_this" when I already have the textarea identified? I don't want to use a class selector on the entire document because I'm working with a large document and class lookups are slow in older browsers.

jQuery .next() doesn't seem to do the trick, closest() only looks up the DOM tree, and .nextUntil() qualifies on everything I need except for the "select_this" div. Any other options out there?

Comment: [Quite related answer on a very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29084305/274502)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are two ways to do it.

Use this if you only have a few siblings:

```
$('textarea').nextAll('div.select_this').first();
```

The downside of this is that it test every subsequent element to see if it matches the selector, even after it's found the first one. Use this if you have *many, many* siblings, to save on evaluation:

```
$('textarea').nextUntil('div.select_this').andSelf().last().next();
```

Note also that it's better to use the [`first`](http://api.jquery.org/first) and [`last`](http://api.jquery.com/last) methods, rather than their corresponding selectors ([`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector), [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector)), because browsers don't natively understand the selectors, which slows the expression down considerably.

*Edited to incorporate `andSelf` per comment below.*

Comment: The second example does not work if the two elements are right next to each other because the nextUntil() call returns an empty set of results.

Comment: The answer should really include what @tnunamak said.

Comment: @tnunamak Answer modified to take this into account.

Answer (score 4):

You want [`nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/):

```
jQuery(yourTextarea).nextAll('.select_this:first');
```

Comment: Curiosity question: by using ":first" does jQuery halt its lookup once it qualifies on the first element, or does it search through the entire DOM and then only return the first element it found?

Comment: @lonesomeday -- dang, that's not good, is there a way to accomplish the former?

Comment: @ElliotB. See my answer, which deals with exactly this point :-)