# JQuery .next() not finding next sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html:

```
<div class="more">▼</div>
<div class="showDescription">blah blah blah</div>
<div class="more">▼</div>
<div class="somethingElse" style="display:none">do do do</div>
<div class="showDescription">blah2 blah2 blah2</div>
```

Class `showDescription` is set to `display:none`

When I click a `▼` I want the next div with class `showDescription` to show, so I'm using:

```
$('.more').click(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html()=='▼'?'▲':'▼').next('.showDescription').stop().fadeToggle();
});
```

Which works perfectly for the first `▼` but not the second, I think because there is something in the way yet I thought `.next()` found the next sibling, which these are?

How can I get around this? And should it actually do this?

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darrensw/vDPZH/7/)

Comment: use `.closest()` or `.nextAll()` instead.

Comment: @gvee: No.  That's not what closest does.

Comment: The `.next()` function looks at the very next element, then compares it to the selector. If it matches then you have a reference to the element, if it doesn't match you have a reference to no elements. It doesn't look at all the elements afterwards until it finds one that matches or runs out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery selector for finding the first element after a given element that matches a selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707340/jquery-selector-for-finding-the-first-element-after-a-given-element-that-matches)

Comment: @RocketHazmat oh dear, how embarrassing! You're quite right, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) will only look at the one directly next, it won't look at all ones next.  You want [`.nextUntil`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/).

```
$('.more').click(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html()=='▼'?'▲':'▼').nextUntil('.more', '.showDescription').stop().fadeToggle();
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/vDPZH/10/

Answer (score 2):

`.next()` will try to fetch only the next element if it satisfies the given selector, in your second case the next sibling is not the `showDescription` element

```
$('.more').click(function () {
    $(this).html(function (_, html) {
        return $.trim(html) == '▼' ? '▲' : '▼'
    }).nextAll('.showDescription').first().stop().fadeToggle();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YHFLf/)