# How to target multiple datepicker in a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a dynamic form with 4 datepicker inputs. How can I target these datepicker inputs to avoid past date after a first date is set?

Here is **[my code](https://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/a3u68d20/1/)**

```
$(function() {
    $( ".from" ).datepicker({
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( ".to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
    $( ".to" ).datepicker({
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( ".from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
  });
```

As you can see both inputs are affected when the user select one date. I want to target one each but as I mentioned my form is dynamic, the user can add 4.. 6.. 8 datepicker inputs.

Comment: Group your from and to dates which would make it easier to target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood this correctly, you want N number of pairs of datepickers ("from" and "to"), which you need to tie together. Essentially, you need a way to go from a specific datepicker and identify only the one other datepicker that's tied to it. There are a number of ways you could do this, but I'd suggest wrapping your pairs in a containing HTML element (`<div>`) then doing the selectors relative to that. Something like this:

```
<div>
    <label class="required">Work from</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control date-picker from input-append minDate" placeholder="mm/yyyy"/><br/>
    <label>Work until </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control date-picker to input-append maxDate" placeholder="mm/yyyy"/>
</div>

<div>
    <label class="required">Study from</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control date-picker from input-append minDate" placeholder="mm/yyyy"/><br/>
    <label>Study until </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control date-picker to input-append maxDate" placeholder="mm/yyyy" />
</div>
```

Then you'd modify your jQuery code for the datepickers to look like this:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".from" ).datepicker({
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $(this).closest('div').find('.to').datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
    $( ".to" ).datepicker({
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $(this).closest('div').find('.from').datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
});
```

The key change is this:

```
$(this).closest('div').find('.from')
```

In the function, `this` is the element of the datepicker that's just closed. `.closest('div')` traverses up the DOM tree until it finds the containing `<div>` element, then `.find('.from')` will find the **one** element with the class `from` inside it, which is the one element that's linked to that specific `to` element.

Comment: Mate you saved our project! =D Thank you so much for your help. Working like a charm! And thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand of your problem, your code is close, but you need to change how you are adding your options. They should use angle ({) brackets.

Try the following:

```
$(function () {
    $(".from").datepicker({
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("." + this.parentElement.className + " .to").datepicker("option", {
                "minDate": selectedDate
            });
        }
    });
    $(".to").datepicker({
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("." + this.parentElement.className + " .from").datepicker("option", {
                "maxDate": selectedDate
            });
        }
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3u68d20/12/)

**Edit**

Another method is to put divs around (or use a special classname within the individual elements), and use that, along with the datepicker type, and change it that way. See the new code above to get an idea of what I mean.

Comment: Still not working :(
Try selecting Work from and Work to dates then select Study dates. You will see that the code is not interpreting each input as unique.

Comment: Oh are you asking if you can have sets together? (for example, the study dates don't affect the work dates, but affect eachother?)

Comment: Exactly. This what I am trying to achieve here. I want to have an unique datepicker group for Study and another group for Work.

Comment: Thank you! Yours is also working fine! I've just realised there are many ways to do it.

Comment: Also do you know if I can change the view format to show months and years only? I wanted to do something like this:  [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ubqih.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(datepicker1,datepicker2,datepicker3,...).datepicker({
    minDate:selectedDate1,
    maxDate:selectedDate2
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.nextUntil()](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) and [.prevUntil()](https://api.jquery.com/prevUntil/) and some additional methods to select only the next or previous input.

```
$(function() {
  $( ".from" ).datepicker({
    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
      $(this).nextUntil('.to').andSelf().last().next().datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
    }
  });
  $( ".to" ).datepicker({
    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
      $(this).prevUntil('.from').prev().datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
    }
  });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kzsb7ajq/)

Answer inspired by [the answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10707433/3002280).